# Application could not be found in the registry

Tags: java, eclipse, console, eclipse-rcp

Sometimes, after a very minor changes in the code, I am loosing the ability to run my Eclipse RCP application. If run, application reports an error

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-12-26 20:42:02.482
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "MY_APPLICATION_NAME" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: SOME_POOR_LIST_OF_APPLICATIONS.
```

For example, last time I lost an ability after:

1) added a function to `ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor` which is not used yet

the code follows:

```
private MessageConsole findConsole(String name) {
    ConsolePlugin plugin = ConsolePlugin.getDefault();
    IConsoleManager conMan = plugin.getConsoleManager();
    IConsole[] existing = conMan.getConsoles();
    for (int i = 0; i < existing.length; i++)
        if (name.equals(existing[i].getName()))
            return (MessageConsole) existing[i];
    // no console found, so create a new one
    MessageConsole myConsole = new MessageConsole(name, null);
    conMan.addConsoles(new IConsole[] { myConsole });
    return myConsole;
}
```

2) which caused an addition of one dependency: `org.eclipse.ui.console`

How all this could cause this error?

Comment: Have you included org.eclipse.ui.console into you run configration (plugins tab)? Does it passes validation?

Comment: I can't say this, because sometimes it works without validation (when validation fails) and sometimes not (when validation passes). Currently it started to work when I set as you say or select all plugins option.

Comment: When adding dependencies to you plugins you should always hit 'add required plugins' button on this page prior to launching.

Comment: Are there some error messages in above of your error message? You could try to run your application with -console flag (in Eclipse). After that OSGI console will be enabled in standard console view. Type 'ss' to get list of plugins with statuses. You could try 'start some_plugin' to start plugin manually and see the error message.